# Excel 2010 Formulas to count data entry for the day

Tags: excel-2010

Each of my entries into my log contain the date it was entered. I would like to make a counter to count all the listings i did today.
The formula i was using is CountIf with E being the range, and the criteria pointing to a cell with the =NOW() formula. .....Doesnt work. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TODAY()` and `COUNTIF()`

```
=COUNTIF(E:E,"="&TODAY())
```

[image: Today]

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked perfectly.